# can I declare a type of an array literal?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

In my typescript code, I have this fragment:

```
pairs.forEach(([n, s]) => {
  console.log(n * 3, s.toUpperCase());
});
```

I want to inline "pairs" variable. I know I can do it this way:

```
([[3, "three"], [5, "five"]] as [number, string][]).forEach(([n, s]) => {
  console.log(n * 3, s.toUpperCase());
});
```

But I don't like it, because now my code became worse. Before inlining, compiler was verifying that each element of the array is a pair of a number and a string - so, for instance, this code does not compile:

```
const pairs: [number, string][] = [[3, "three"], [5, "five"], ["seven", 7]];
pairs.forEach(([n, s]) => {
  console.log(n * 3, s.toUpperCase());
});
```

But after inline, a type of my array is not declared. Instead, I use a type assertion, which tells the compiler to ignore what it thinks the type is and take my word for what this type is. So now compiler does not verify that each element of the array is a pair of a number and a string. So, for instance, this code compiles, and only fails in runtime:

```
([[3, "three"], [5, "five"], ["seven", 7]] as [number, string][]).forEach(([n, s]) => {
  console.log(n * 3, s.toUpperCase());
});
```

Can I somehow have both things - both have this array inlined and tell compiler what is its type? Can I somehow declare a type of an array literal?

Comment: "*Instead, I use a cast, which happens in runtime,*" no, that's not true for two reasons: 1. There are no *casts* in TypeScript. You've used a *type assertion*. It may sound like just semantics but it *is* different. 2. More specifically type assertions *do not happen at runtime*. They are compiletime instructions to tell TS to ignore what it thinks the type is and take your word for what this type is.  Yes, that leads to the problem you describe but *not* because something happens later. It's because type assertions are lying to the compiler. Thus type assertions lead to runtime problems.

Comment: Maybe the const assertion `as const` would do almost the same but shorter (it's readonly now which seems fine for this case)

Comment: Thank you, VLAZ. It does not solve my problem, but is a good thing to understand. I edited the question to have it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't really do it automatically.

In `let pairs = [[3, "three"], [5, "five"]]`, the type of `pairs` is auto-detected as `(string | number)[][]` rather than as `([number,string][] )`
That's why after inlining, it doesn't behave like you wished, it'll just use the `(string | number)[][]` that it inferred.

It seems that the auto-detect tries to detect a variable-length array rather than a tuple whenever it has the chance. 
So, `let x = [3,4]` is detected as `number[]` rather than `[number,number]`
And
`let pair = [3,'three']` is detected as `(string|number)[]` rather than `[number,string]`

[image]

Comment: @JoãoFerreira Can you should un-accept this post and accept the other answer instead?

Answer (score 2):

The magic words you’re looking for are `as const`:

```
([[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar'], [3, 'baz']] as const)
  .forEach(([n, s]) => console.log(n * 3, s.toLocaleUpperCase()));
```

Note that `as const` goes further than you’re looking for here: the type of this array is

```
readonly [readonly [1, "foo"], readonly [2, "bar"], readonly [3, "baz"]]
```

And `n` has type `1 | 2 | 3` rather than `number` and `s` has type `"foo" | "bar" | "baz"` rather than `string`. The `readonly` marker can be particularly annoying, since a `readonly T[]` is not assignable to a `T[]`.

I use `as const` a lot, because it’s really powerful, but I also often use a utility function when I want to create such tuples, but *don’t* want to turn things into `readonly` arrays of specific literals:

```
function tuple<T extends unknown[]>(...args: T): T { return args; }
```

(Note that as an actual function, this does introduce runtime overhead—`as const` does not. It’s extremely minuscule however.)

With this, we can use

```
tuple(tuple(1, 'foo'), tuple(2, 'bar'), tuple(3, 'baz'))
  .forEach(([n, s]) => console.log(n * 3, s.toLocaleUpperCase()));
```

and now our array is `[[number, string], [number, string], [number, string]]` and `n` is just `number` and `s` is just `string`.

[See all of this in the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQbREYBoAIHIDMD2jYF0YgEw1gIwIYBOaGAzDgQF5qrT4DO0AxogHb0AuAlAFDTQA6JIQCi+JgAtgoVjHqou0ALwA+Zm3qIANgFMBWxAHNgraACpo5aPQEdEAGURN8ugKoAHdzsIBhBjuAuIIBuHh4Wdg5oQmVoMCg4JBR0OOw4AmIUkCs8fGpUWgZ1SNCeeABXViYOAEs2aA5y910AHgAVaB0ADw4dVgATRkqAa1ZEAHdWEFQVYAF5okN6AC5oNq5VjoBvaJ1GwlNF+mDoAF8wiM4G2MbmgNvdYASEZFguGAeAtNzid4amx45KhvLilT7AcHPJJvD4Ar4UIgw-53YBAvIgviCYRiSTSECyawKZRqS7aPQGYymCxWGx2RzONyebx+egBIKgnhAA)